# Integrate express api in existing angular 9 application

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, e-commerce, integration

i am pretty new into coding and this is my first question, so dont be too hard with me :)

I bought an existing angular 9 Frontend Online Store which uses mock data stored inside a JSON file in the src folder. (which contain information of the products of my online Shop). 
Now i'm building the Backend and followed a tutorial on how to build a restful api using express and Mongodb. I successfully programmed a get (and post, update and delete) function, which take JSON data from the MongoDB Server and post it inside postman:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   try {
        const posts = await Post.find();    
        res.json(posts);
   } catch (err) {
        res.json (err);
   }
```

(It routes to my MongoDB server using the .env file).

Now i want to make it useful and **integrate it in my angular project, so when the main page loads, the JSONs of my products load in an array**, so i can display the Products.

Home Five is the main page where some products are displayed and got from the mock data file products.json2 using the service class.  Here is the code

```
ngOnInit() {
this.productService.getProducts()
.subscribe(
  (product: Product[]) => {
  this.products = product;
  }
)}
```

code from the service class:

```
      public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.products(); 
      }
private products(): Observable<Product[]> {
      return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>('assets/data/products2.json');                  
    }
```

Now im wondering, how exactly to use these functions, but take the data from MongoDB. 
My Thoughts are as following:
1) put my rest api functions inside the ngOninit, so they are triggered when the page loads, which loads the data directly from my database. But im wondering how this is possible, bec. angular is written in TS and my api is written in JS.

2) Load all data from db when my domain loads the first time, store it in products2.json and use it like the mock data.

What do you guys think what to do and how? I am new to coding, so i would be very grateful if you could explain me what to do in a deeper way and or give some code examples.

Again, i hope my question is deep enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first expose the APIs. Then use Angular HttpClient module from @angular/common/http and the code in your service would look like below:

```
private products(): Observable<Product[]> {
   const options = {};

   return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:3000/', options);                  
}
```